# How to change storage::get to database (Laravel 5.2.45)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have code like this:

```
public function storeTrainingOne($id,$type)
    {
          $tweet = DB::table('tweets')->where('id',$id)->first();
          if($type=='netral')
          {
            $netral = Storage::get('public/netral.txt');
            Storage::put('public/netral.txt',$netral."\n".$tweet->tweet);
            Session::flash('message','<div class="alert alert-success">
                                    success, click <a href="'.URL('/training#netral').'">here</a>
                                </div>');
            return redirect()->back();
          }
          elseif($type=='positif')
          {
              $positif = Storage::get('public/positif.txt');
              Storage::put('public/positif.txt',$positif."\n".$tweet->tweet);
              Session::flash('message','<div class="alert alert-success">
                                    success, click<a href="'.URL('/training#positif').'">here</a>
                                </div>');
              return redirect()->back();
          }
          else
          {
              $negatif = Storage::get('public/negatif.txt');
              Storage::put('public/negatif.txt',$negatif."\n".$tweet->tweet);
              Session::flash('message','<div class="alert alert-success">
                                    success, click<a href="'.URL('/training#negatif').'">here</a>
                                </div>');
              return redirect()->back();
          }
    }
```

So how change it to database? data can transfer to my database, not on my file, i has been changed to DB::table but it's still not working now. So how i can do it to connect my data to database, not to my file .txt

Thanks

Comment: If you want to store stuff in the database, use the `DB` class or Eloquent. The `Storage` class doesn't have a database driver.

Comment: You want to save file content in your database? Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Require more information... What you want to achieve?

Comment: this code has been updated, i'm changed to DB:table but still can't work to send data on my database. The data is tweet on Twitter. My database table is Laravel.